Via-in-pad or Via between pads of resistor and the corresponding copper area
I'm new to PCB layout design. I'm trying to design a series o driver circuits. I was wondering if a via could be placed either in between the pads of a current limiting resistor or right in the pad of the resistor, as indicated in the image below.
For reference, the copper weight used for the board is 2oz and it is a 4 layer board (Signal & components, GND, Power and Signal).  This particular via would be a buried via, from the top layer to 3rd layer (pwr plane). The currents through the one onme where the via would be connecte4d to would be 10A.
My question is, can this be done? Will it effect the soldering of the pads? What can I do to ensure that the soldering will not be compromised if I place the buried via in between the pads or in the pad?


If your question is only about solderability, If you are placing it between pads, it does not affect. if you are using via on the pads, you can do via capping. so it won't affect the solderability.

You're using buried vias on a 4 layer board? Are you sure you need that and that your manufacturer will provide that?

@user1850479 Yes, I am using a buried via for a 4-layer board as this was one of the requirements for this project

@shafeeq does the thicker copper area around the pad won't affect the soldering?

Ten amps through one via? That seems like a problem either way.

@Hearth Would parallel vias be the way to go then?

Via-in-pad is common, but it does cost extra. Do you have a reason to want to pay extra?

Just to make sure, you do realize that you can use a through via to connect between inner layers, right? (we do occasionally get questions from beginners who don't know this)

Buried / blind vias are usually symmetrical, meaning that you could have a via traverse 1-2-3-4, 1-2, 2-3, or 3-4... but 1-2-3 would be uncommon... as above, are you aware of the cost implications, and are you sure this is something you can actually get made? I'm certainly intrigued by project and its requirements!

@ThePhoton I didn't realise I could use a through via instead of a buried one. Could I still use multiple parallel vias in pad or between the pads? As for going with a via-in-pad option, the board is small and there are space constraints. Via-in-pad or between pads seemed like a good alternative

As long as it follows the clearance rules for your manufacturer it can be done. It won't affect the soldering of the pads, but realize whenever copper or vias (especially those that go to a large copper plane underneath) are placed around pads, they can wick away heat during soldering and sometimes cause problems. A via like this probably won't cause problems, but designers need to be aware of this. If it is a problem, use thermal relief traces around the pads.
If you place the via in the pads, they need to be filled and plated. If they aren't (sometimes you can get away with it, not recommended especially for high yield designs), the solder can wick down the via during reflow and take solder away from the SMT device and cause it to not solder properly. Plating makes it so the via hole is plated over and this will not occur.
Find the resistance of the via with a via calculator tool (like the one in saturn PCB toolkit) and make sure the temperature rise through the via won't be too high. If your 10A is for a DC/DC converter,it's likely that the parasitic inductance will also be a problem and you will need to parallel multiple vias.

Yes, it is DC/DC. I used a similar calculator to find the reqd drill diameter for 10A current while I input the rest of the parametrs and It says I need a via with drill diameter of 1.8165mm. Would this suffice? Or would I also have to add parallel vias? (Input parameters - Ambient temp of 50 degrees, plating thickness of 2oz, via height of 1.049mm, max current of 10A)

You can use one big via smaller parallel via are better for space reasons

Could I use multiple smaller parallel vias in between and on the pads instead of one big one? And could I use a through via instead of a buried via?

Try to avoid Vias in pad if you can, it will incur extra costs and the radius mentioned in the answer. You can use though vias.
